# How do I convert a UserObject_ model I get from Tensorflow Hub model to a tflite model?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub, tensorflow-lite

I've been trying to convert the universal-sentence-encoder-4 model into a tflite model for the past three hours.

I can't turn the model into a concrete function because the imported model, which is a UserObject_, doesn't have variables such as import or shape.

If I save the model and then use tf.lite.converter, I get the error "ValueError: as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape"

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using `tf.keras.models.load_model` instead of `tf.saved_model.load` ? The former returns much more keras like object.

Comment: @sebastian-sz I have, and I get the same problems